# Why doesn't Python see my file, even though it can connect to the server via smb?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to rename the file, I can see it when I print out the shared file.filename, but it gives an error saying its not there

```
import os, datetime
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
from datetime import date, datetime

userID = 'username'
password = 'mypsswrd$'
client_machine_name = 'localpcname'
server_name = 'hostname'
server_ip = '10.28.7.249'

domain_name = 'domain name'
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

conn = SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, server_name, domain=domain_name, use_ntlm_v2=True,
                     is_direct_tcp=True)
conn.connect(server_ip, 445)

shares = conn.listShares()

for share in shares:
    if not share.isSpecial and share.name not in ['NETLOGON', 'SYSVOL']:
        sharedfiles = conn.listPath(share.name, '/')
        for sharedfile in sharedfiles:
            print(sharedfile.filename)

#change name
newname = 'CS_Out_Of_Country' + date_time +'.csv'
os.rename('CS_Out_Of_Country.csv', newname)

#Copy to archive

#close the connection
conn.close()
```

the connection works fine and I can see my csv file but it says it doesn't exist, how come?

Answer (score 0):

`os.rename` operates in the current working directory. It doesn't know about the smb connection you created before. To fix this, you should either

- Mount the smb share into the local filesystem, then os.chdir() to said mountpoint and then run os.rename() OR
- use [SMBConnection.rename](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.rename) (disclaimer: I've never used pysmb before, but that's what I found in 5 seconds using google.)